# Определённый случай правописания не с наречием

Tags: частица-не, наречия

Друзья, есть у меня один извечный философский вопрос. После своей победы игрок пишет: «Это было не сложно». Рассмотрим слово «не сложно», оно просто обязано писаться слитно, ведь мы можем заменить его на синоним «легко», и никаких противопоставлений здесь не имеется, также как слов: отнюдь, вовсе, и тд. На такое заявление мне отвечают: «Видимо, автор хотел именно усилить отрицательное значение, чтобы подчеркнуть соревновательный элемент, поэтому «не сложно» в данном случае пишется раздельно». Как дотошно объяснить кто прав?

Answer (score 1):

Основной принцип правила следующий:
**НЕ + ПРИЛАГАТЕЛЬНОЕ = ПРОТИВОПОЛОЖНОЕ ЗНАЧЕНИЕ — ПИШЕМ СЛИТНО**
**НЕ + ПРИЛАГАТЕЛЬНОЕ = ОТСУТСТВИЕ ХАРАКТЕРИСТИКИ — ПИШЕМ РАЗДЕЛЬНО**
Для наречия характеристики действия так же.
‟Не сложно” может быть как слитно, так и раздельно.

— Я видел, что тебе было сложно в этом бою.
— Я не согласен, мне было не сложно, просто сперва непривычно.

— Вы нокаутировали соперника в первом раунде.
— Он мало двигался, так что было несложно попасть.

Если спортсмен скажет просто: ‟Это было не сложно”, то тут может быть два значения в зависимости от контекста и, соответственно, того, что человек хочет обозначить.
Это было не сложно (Отрицается сложность, но не утверждается легкость победы. Не сложно, но нормально, например.)
Это было несложно (Утверждается легкость.)

Конечно, если есть слова ‟вовсе”, ‟отнюдь”, то есть противопоставление чьему-то мнению или ожиданиям, которые есть в контексте, и ‟не” пишется раздельно.

Answer (score 1):

Вы правы. И здесь играет роль стилистика.

Написание с частицей НЕ среди прочего проверяется подстановкой глагола "быть" (что больше подходит):
*Он был неправ.

Он не был прав.*
В связи с этим глагол "быть" указывает на качество (слитное написание), есть слова такого типа (например, *стать, оказаться*).

Из-за этого вариант "*это было не сложно*" не особо удачен в плане стилистики, его следует заменить на "*это не было сложно*".
Даже и с противопоставлением в связи с этим всем не очень звучит (стилистика не особо удачна), но необходимо писать раздельно:
*Это было не сложно, а легко.*
Удачный вариант:
*Это не было сложно, было легко.*